# I have always been pushing vs. I have always pushed?

Tags: present-perfect, present-continuous

A mother and a daughter are talking about studies.

Then the mother says that the daughter has just got well in the exams because this:

**"But that's only because I have always pushed you to do something."**  (Sentence 1)

The year is not finished yet and the daughter is still on school.

If the important action is *pushing* the girl to do her homework, why not use:

**"But that's only because I have always been pushing you to do something."**
 (Sentence 2)

Does the word ***always*** create a continuous sense?

What are the differences in sense between the two sentences?

Comment: You might find this link helpful: [I have been eating vs. I have eaten](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/i-have-been-eating-present-perfect-continuous-vs-i-have-eaten-present-perfect-simple)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is probably true that the mother is still pushing the daughter to do her homework.

However, the mother's pushing the daughter ***now*** does not provide a reason for the daughter's having done well on a ***past*** exam. That can only be attributed to pushing in the past. Consequently, the perfect is in order here.

Note that this is an *experiential* perfect, not a *resultative* perfect—it characterizes the pushing as an element in the mother and daughter's current shared experience. The resultative burden is carried by the preposition *because*, and in a formal argument this would call for a simple past or past perfect (and in fact, most US speakers would probably employ a simple past here: "You got an A because I always pushed you."). But that sort of precision is unnecessary in colloquial contexts; in the context of a present or perfect in the main clause the present perfect maintains temporal harmony between the two clauses—"You've {got / gotten} an A because I've always pushed you."

Answer (score 2):

**Present perfect simple and present perfect continuous**

> 1. We use the present perfect continuous form for an action **in progress** and, the simple form for a **completed** action.
>
> — *I've been learning Russian, but I can't speak it well.*
>
> — *I've learnt a new piece on the piano. I can play it now.*
>
> 2. We use the continuous form for something which has been happening **recently** and **repeatedly:**
>
> — *I haven't been doing my homework this term.*
>
> But we use the simple form for one occasion or an exact number of occasions:
>
> — *I haven't done my project/my last three projects.*
>
> 3. We can use the simple or continuous form with ***for*** or ***since*** to say **how long** a current action has been in progress. The continuous form is more frequent:
>
> — *I've been waiting/I've waited for hours!*

Since **always** it's used for **repeated** actions (you can also use it for the **present simple**), you use the continuous form.

Answer (score 2):

You usually use the present perfect for recent actions that have results in the present.  In light of this description and the answer of our respectable  teacher, StoneyB, I think the use of the present perfect in the sentence  under discussion is more appropriate. As Americans also use the past simple in this situation, you can use either the past simple or the present perfect in this sentence.

As for the present perfect continuous, it indicates an ongoing action; the action that started in the past and still continues in the present.

As the mother's action (pushing her daughter) is an ongoing action, the use of the present perfect continuous is also  correct grammatically.

Besides, you can sometimes use the present perfect continuous to replace the present perfect to imply a recently completed action in addition to its normal sense of an ongoing action. Please look at the following sentences:

He said, "Why are you so wet".  "I have been swimming", she replied.

The sentence " I have been swimming"  indicates the action recently completed.

So you can say "But that's because I have pushed you/have been pushing you to do something".

The adverb always is used to imply at all times, repeatedly, continually, etc. Its use in a sentence doesn't mean that the sentence is in the continuous form.